# Displaying Multi-Value Parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have a multi-valued parameter which has about 25 elements in it. If the user selects "Select All" and I use the standard (at least as far as I know) method of displaying the parameter at the top of the report:

```vb
=join(Parameters!ProductClass.Value, ",")
```

Rather than the the word "All" or something I get:

```
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,25,30,31,98,99
```

There isn't a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of values selected and compare it to the total number of records in the data set that populates the parameter.

```
=IIF(Parameters!ProductClass.Count = Count(Fields!CaseSensitiveFieldName.Value, "CaseSensitiveDataSetName"), "All", Join(Parameters!ProductClass.Value, ","))
```