# SSRS avoid WHERE clause if select all is selected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on an SSRS report and a part of my sql query is like

```
WHERE SuperVisorId IN (@SupervisorIDs) AND CreatedDate> @StartDate
```

where the @SupervisorIDs is a dropdown with option of "select all" and individual supervisors.

So if the supervisors "all" option is selected , then I don't need to include that in the where clause and my where clause is only this

```
  WHERE CreatedDate> @StartDate
```

So how can I make the WHERE clause looks different according to Selection of dropdown?

Comment: How about `WHERE (@SupervisorIDs = 'All' OR SuperVisorId IN (@SupervisorIDs)) AND CreatedDate > @StartDate`, provided that you actually put "All" for the parameter when all the options in SSRS are selected in the multiselect dropdown menu.

Comment: But what happend when we select a specific value of supervisor and that time it will return both "all" and "selected" rows right and i guess thats wrong . The intention of question is to know possibility to  use conditional where clause based on dropdown selection

Comment: since there are some rows in db with value NULL and i have to handle null values as well if i select the option 'select all' and i have to skip null values if a specific 'supervisor'  is selected

Comment: Is the parameter a single or multi valued parameter?

Comment: its multivalued param

Comment: Then what you are asking is not functionally possible.  The `select all` option in the dropdown menu literally just ticks all the options and passes them all to the query as a list.  It isn't sending an `all` value, it is just sending every single option at the same time.  The only way you can skip this processing is by manually adding an `All` option to the top of a single valued parameter list and using logic similar to my answer below.

Comment: real problem is some rows have null values and if select all is there then the querry will not consider the null value rows 
So i want to include null values only if "select all" is choosen Thats why i decided to skip where condition in that case
and use where condition if "select all" is unticked.

Comment: As I say, there is no way to pass a `I have clicked the select all` flag.  Just change your query to handle the `nulls`, for example adding an option in your parameter selection for `N/A` or `Missing` at the bottom and in your dataset return the `null` values where this value is selected.

Answer (score 1):

## This only applies if you are using a single valued parameter with a manually added `All` option to the list of available values.  Multi-value parameters do not know when all options are selected.

SQL Server doesn't always execute the conditions in a `where` clause in the order you write them, so if you are using `where (@p = 'all' or col = @p) and ...` you may still be comparing your values.

If performance is a concern, you can avoid this by using a short circuiting `case`, that only progresses to the actual data comparison if it is necessary:

```
where case when @SupervisorIDs = 'All' then 1
           else case when SuperVisorId = @SupervisorIDs then 1
                     else 0
                     end
           end = 1
  and CreatedDate > @StartDate
```

Comment: but then can we limit the selection to 'all'  only in the beggining by default? Or will select all will be displayed at same time as selected

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a dataset query to populate the supervisor parameter dropdown, then you can try this.

Create an additional hidden parameter of a boolean type.  For this example, I'll call it @AllSupsSelected.  Set the default value of the parameter to:
=COUNT(Parameters!SupervisorIds.Label)=COUNT(Fields!SupervisorIdLabel.Value,"SupervisorDataset")

Replace the field and dataset names accordingly.  If the dataset is returning non-distinct values, you may have to tinker further to get this working.

Now your query can read:

WHERE @AllSupsSelected OR SupervisorId IN (@SupervisorIds)

Comment: I got this error 
An error occurred while executing the query.
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'.Incorrect syntax near ')'


And my query is like 

FROM LoginSession 
 WHERE   
       CreatedDate >  '@'BeginDate 
 AND CreatedDate <  '@'EndDate 
AND '@'AllSelected OR  SupervisorId IN ('@'SupervisorIds)

Comment: Sorry, I'm answering/commenting on a mobile phone without much chance to test.  You may need to try either @AllSelected=True or @AllSelected='True'.

Comment: I have this error: A Value expression used for the report parameter ‘AllPeopleSelected’ refers to a field.  Fields cannot be used in report parameter expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Make your where clause like below

```
WHERE (
        (SuperVisorId IN (@SupervisorIDs))
        OR (
            @SupervisorIDs = 0
            AND COLUMN_WITH_NULL IS NOT NULL
            )
        )
    AND CreatedDate > @StartDate
```

And pass 0 when selected  "select all"

Comment: but how can i pass 0 to ssrs dropdown for selct all . My intention of this question is to check possibility of writing conditional query based on input of dropdown

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704453/ssrs-can-i-know-if-user-selected-all-in-multivalued-param check if select all then change response to 0 if true

Comment: @JibinMathew, you must be passing any value for "SupervisorIDs".apart from what discuss here,you also need to check "filter","formua" option in SSRS.I don't remember the exact term.

Comment: @KumarHarsh Thats very promising . But can we use that as a part of dataset SQL querry

Comment: do u hv parameter define in your SSRS or not ?what you pass in those param and how r u using it ?

Comment: Yes i am using params and its like WHERE CreatedDate >  '@'BeginDate 
 AND CreatedDate <  '@'EndDate 
 AND SuperVisorId IN ('@'SuperVisorIds)

Answer (score 0):

As an actual answer to your particular problem, set your multi-valued parameter dataset up similar to this to return all `Supervisors` as well as a value at the bottom of the list for `No Supervisor`:

```
select distinct SupervisorID as Value
               ,SupervisorName as Label
               ,1 as Sort
from Suppliers

union all

select <Uniquely identifiable value with the same data type as SupervisorID> as Value
      ,'No Supervisor' as Label
      ,2 as Sort

order by Sort
        ,Label
```

Then in your dataset set up your filtering similar to the below.  I have structured it in this manner to avoid using the `isnull` function on your `SupervisorID` column, which will hurt the query performance:

```
select cols
from tables
where SupervisorID in(@SupervisorID)
   or (SupervisorID is null
       and <Unique value from above> in (@SupervisorID)
      )
```

Answer (score -1):

which version of ssrs ? in 2016, you don't need to alter your query. when you click "select all"  by default it pass all the values. so your query works good without changing anything.

thanks,
SK[image]

Comment: OP is wondering how to include values that aren't passed if all options are selected.  I don't think this correctly answers that.