# Detect when (Select All) is checked for multi value parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with a multi-valued parameter on it. I'm looking to output the selected values which is accomplished with `Join(Parameters!State.Label,",")`

Every solution I've found on the web indicates I should use something like the following to detect when the (Select All) "value" is selected.

E.g. expression for the text box on the header should be:

```
="State: " & IIF(countrows("prc_prompt_state").Equals(Parameters!State.Count),"(All)",join(Parameters!State.Label,","))
```

CountRows() tells me the total number of parameters available, e.g. 8 states in Australia. Parameters!State.Count is *supposed* to tell me how many are actually selected by the user. However this always reports the full value (8 in this case) regardless of how many are selected. This is in agreement with the official docs (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337293(v=sql.100).aspx), but NOT in agreement with every single search result I come up with on how to solve this problem.

**So how can I rewrite this expression so I can find out when (Select All) is/isn't checked?** I'm using report builder 3, which I believe is based on the 2008 edition - we deploy to Azure, but I haven't got that far yet.

Examples of questions whose answers seem to be wrong:

[Displaying Multi-Value Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480463/displaying-multi-value-parameters/3481181#3481181)

[SSRS: Can I know if user selected "ALL" in multivalued param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704453/ssrs-can-i-know-if-user-selected-all-in-multivalued-param)

Comment: 1. `countrows()` tells you the number of rows in the dataset "prc_prompt_state", i.e. the total number of states available. 2. `Parameters!State.Count` indeed tells you the number of states selected. 3. It works perfectly on my system. 4. Nowhere in the official docs is it mentioned that you will see all the available values and not the selected ones. It says - Refers to the number of values. For a single-value parameter, the count is always 1. For a multivalue parameter, the count is 0 or more.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti #2/#3 it isn't working like that for me, hence the question. I've even tried just outputting the value of the expressions alone (without the IFF statement, etc) - `Parameters!State.Count` never varies regardless of how many are selected. (It always gives the same as `countrows()` #4 the phrase `Refers to the number of values` is very vague - it could be validly interpreted as either 'selected' or 'available' values. `The count is 0 or more` is true - it doesn't tell you whether the count varies depending on the selection or not.

Comment: Very strange. I got the result of Parameters!State.Count in a dummy report and each time, I selected x number of parameters from the list, the output was x. Can you attach a few screenshots of how you are selecting the parameters and how the output looks like.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I recreated the data set and parameters then it all worked properly as you/the examples say. The really strange thing is that the old and rebuilt files are bitwise identical... After this I was able to go back to my original file and it was suddenly working. (SO question: do I need to tag you in comments like this for you to get a notification, or does that happen automatically since you're already participating?)

Comment: I will get the notification if I my comment is part of the thread. But a sure shot way to get me notified is to tag me. And glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but google found it for me, and then I figured out an answer on my own that worked. (I was using a list of users.)

I created a separate dataset that returns a count of all available options in the default parameter lookup (username).  Then, I assigned that as a default value to an internal parameter. (UserCount)  This worked as a text expression:

```
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.IIF(Parameters!username.Count = Parameters!UserCount.Value, "All Selected", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.JOIN(Parameters!username.Value, ", "))
```